# Migrate from Godaddy hosting to Microsoft

Tags: email, dns, hosting

I am tasked to move domain, web, email hosting in Godaddy to Microsoft.
I'm  not sure of where to start but this is what I have and know.

- we have a domain name(xxx.com) hosted in Godaddy.
- we have website hosted there([www.xxx.com](http://www.xxx.com))
- we have emails created there- 14 users(eg company@xxx.com)

I need to move everything from Godaddy to Microsoft.

Kindly assist on the way forward here, would also appreciate if you could breakdown the pricing for all that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

May I know why you want to move your website to Microsoft? Have you checked Azure pricing? The fee is depend on the resources that you need. You can check their calculator pricing first for further info. For domain name, you can just point it to Azure name server in order to host it.

Comment: Most of the applications that we use are from Microsoft, we just want everything in one basket
Kindly share how/where will I host my domain, email and website AND also how to migrate everything to GoDaddy.

Comment: 1. Sign up first with Azure
2. Please upload all your files to Azure server
3. For emails, you can setup Outlook first so all your emails will be automatically backed up to your Outlook.
4. Once it is done, you can then point your domain to Azure name server.